# Piecewise linear / spline regression: explaining changes in standard error

Tags: standard-error, splines, piecewise-linear

I have a model to estimate the effect of gas prices on a dependent variable `Y`.  In the piecewise linear regression model (Gujarati 1995, p.519), I included a dummy variable indicating gas prices exceeding \$3 (gas price >\$3 $\rightarrow$ D\$3).  In addition to the main gasoline price variable (the log of GP), I included an interactive term `[log(GP)-log(3)] * D$3]`.  So the model is:

```
log Y = a + beta1*log(GP) + beta2*D$3 + beta3*[log(GP)-log(3)] * D$3] + ...
```

I would like to test if elasticity changes at the \$3 mark.

The results show that `beta1` is statistically insignificant.  However, when I flip (0 / 1) for D\$3 and created a variable `[log(GP)-log(3)]` that has a value for gas price < \$3 and 0 for gas price > \$3, `beta1` becomes statistically significant.  Not only the estimated coefficient becomes larger (expected), but the standard error also becomes smaller.

```
               Coef.   Std. Err.     t    P>|t| 
TRY 1: beta1 |   .0312231   .0273001     1.14   0.253 
       beta3 |   .1484264   .0560878     2.65   0.008 

TRY 2: beta1 |   .1796495    .052143     3.45   0.001 
       beta3 |  -.1484264   .0560878    -2.65   0.008

[ 0.0312 + 0.1484 = 0.1796 ]
```

I understand what's going on in terms of estimated coefficients.

Does anyone have any explanation for what causes this change in statistical significance for `beta1`?  Certainly, there are more observations with gas price < \$3 (72 obs) than those with gas price > \$3 (41 obs).

Given statistical significance depends on how to create variables, is there any guidance for what to do in this situation?

When I interpret results, can or should I include the direct effect (`beta1`) regardless of statistical significance in Try1?

Thank you for your inputs in advance.